# django-registration "remember me"

Tags: django, django-registration

I need to implement a "Remember me" button in a login form that uses the django-registration app. Any ane can help me showing me the way for do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do it is to change the session expiration date.  This snippet gives an example: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1881/

Comment: Something's wrong with this link. Here it is: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1881/ It's the www. prepended that's not routed.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there's module for that:

http://code.google.com/p/django-remember-me/

I haven't used it but it came up during my search.