# Django Login Form with "Remember Me" Option, What would be the best way?

Tags: python, django, authentication, remember-me

I am developing a django application and i would like some suggestions on what would be the best way to provide "Remember Me" option with the Login Form. I am really concerned about the performance of the application and am not sure if using sessions would be a good choice. Please Suggest What you think.

Answer (score 3):

Have it provide a cookie with no expire date or a very large one.

Comment: Most sites which provide a remember me feature makes it valid for 2 weeks, so I guess that's a good limit.

Comment: is't two weeks long expiration enabled by default with SESSION_COOKIE_AGE?

Answer (score 0):

See this question:

[django-registration "remember me"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770370/django-registration-remember-me/6302853#6302853)